# Regex finds just once

Tags: python, regex, django, django-templates

I have an regex for a django template tag to find expressions like '(bkz: something)'. Here's my code:

```
@register.filter(name='bkzs')
def bkzs(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<start>.*)\(bkz: (?P<bkz>.*)\)(?P<end>.*)")
    link = r'\g<start>(bkz: <a href="/baslik/\g<bkz>"  title="\g<bkz>">\g<bkz></a>)\g<end>'
    text = pattern.sub(link, text)
```

It works but it just works once. It pairs the last paired part in a text.
As you can see it finds '(bkz: something)'s in text and adds hyperlinks to them but for instance when our text is "(bkz: lorem) (bkz: ipsum) (bkz: dolor)", it just adds hyperlink to "(bkz: dolor)" part. How can I make this work for all 'bkz's in my text?
Thanks.

Comment: `re.findall(regex, stringToSearch)`

Comment: Beware of .* it is greedy.

Comment: How should I use re.findall(regex, stringToSearch) in this case? I'm very new at these stuff.

Comment: What should I use instead of .*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lazy matching:

```
r"(?P<start>.*?)\(bkz: (?P<bkz>.*?)\)(?P<end>.*?)"
```

Since, your pattern needs data from `bkz:` until it finds the closing parantheses; you can use that information as well:

```
r"(?P<start>.*?)\(bkz: (?P<bkz>[^)]*)\)(?P<end>.*?)"
```